# System.Diagnostics ServiceModel message logging not working for integration test project

Tags: wcf, system.diagnostics

I have an integration test project, that I run tests on my classes that consume an external WCF service

In `MyApp.IntegrationTests` I have an `app.config` file that looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>

  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>

  </appSettings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      -- ommitted for brevity
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint name="IWhatever"
                address="https://url.com/Whatever.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="basicHttpsBindingConfiguration"
                contract="IWhatever" />

    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
          <add initializeData="soap-log.xml" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
            name="messages" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

As you can see, I'm trying to log my calls to `soap-log.xml`

If I run my tests, no log file is created.

What is confusing me is, if I have the `system.diagnostics` block in my actual web app project, the xml log file is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's seems you missed `messageLogging` element. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) link.

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <diagnostics>
    <messageLogging 
         logEntireMessage="true" 
         logMalformedMessages="true"
         logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" 
         logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false"
         maxMessagesToLog="3000"
         maxSizeOfMessageToLog="20000"/>
  </diagnostics>
</system.serviceModel>
```